# Set cookie expiration date to exact time

Tags: php, html, cookies

I'm trying to make cookies expire at an exact time. For example, I wish my cookie to expire everyday at 12:00pm. 
As I understand you don't choose an expiration date, but a lifetime.
Must I do 12pm-time() or something similar? If so, how would I achieve that?

Thank you!

Comment: Your tags include PHP and javascript, which do you use to handle your cookies?

Comment: @Salketer I edited the question and removed irrelevant tags, feeling that both PHP and HTML are related to cookies. You may also suggest an edit.

Comment: in PHP `setcookie` accept exact timestamp for the expiration, and not a lifetime, meaning that you should do `time() + $lifetime` to use a lifetime approach.

Comment: Using php. Sorry for that. Thank you Fred.

Comment: @JoColina You're quite welcome.

Comment: You could use php to get the number of seconds between now and 12 p.m., and set the cookie to expire after that many seconds. It could be off by a couple milliseconds, but that probably wont be noticeable.

Comment: @JoColina People are starting to post answers. As for what I can tell you is, and in a nutshell is that, your cookie needs to be set inside an `if{ // between this time and this time // do something }` statement. If it meets that criteria, then the cookie will either be set or unset, depending on your choice. Another thing is that, times will differ from countries, states/provinces etc., so keep that in mind.

Comment: @Fred Are you sure that the timezones will have make the times differ? I would think that the server time and user time get adjusted, as the cookie expirations usually includes a timezone indicator

Comment: @Salketer It will or could matter if the OP plans on using it for special events or something of that nature. If there's a way to synchronize it using an offset (I figure), then that would be a bonus. *"Just saying"* (wink)

Comment: @Salketer You're very much welcome. *"Peace"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give a timestamp for a cookie lifetime, so you need to find the timestamp of next noon.

```
$noon = strtotime('noon', time());
if($noon<=time())// Already past, get tomorrow
    $noon = strtotime('Tomorrow noon', time());
setCookie("my_cookie","my_cookie_value",$noon);
```

Edit: note that the second parametre in strtotime is superfluous as it is time() by default.

Comment: And then I woudl just pass $noon to the setcookie() function? Thus allowing me to make it expire everyday at noon right?

Comment: typo: noon -> $noon in the last line

Comment: @JoColina Timezones will differ, remember that. See my added comment underneath your question. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use `strtotime` in your case.

```
$expire = strtotime('today 12pm');
if (time() > $expire) {
    $expire = strtotime('tomorrow 12pm');
}
setcookie('foobar', '1', $expire);
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, `time()` helps you get the current time, then set dates relative to that time.

Cookies take a single point of time as the expiration date, so if you want it to be 12:00 pm, just set it as such, without taking into account the current time, which you don't care about.